# can not run all tests with ant and java

Tags: xml, ant, junit

does anyone know how I can run all of tests with ant and java(build.xml) without eclipse through  script.

I created a build.xml from eclipse then I want to run all the tests in the project build by ant through command prompt, and have one report for all of them with each test sepcified in the report if passed or failed.

Pleas help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `cd` into the directory that contains the `build.xml` file and run the command `ant`.  It will expect to find a `build.xml` file and then will execute the default target.

Comment: yes but it only executes the defult target I have some junit tests(.java files) in one project and I want to run them all one after each other I mean all the targets together, I read something about batchset but I dont know how it works its not clear for me.

Comment: Thanks guys I did I think, I have another question, does anyone know, if I can run my build.xml outside my java workspace? from another directory? also is it possible to export the report also in one file in another directory?

Comment: @user3738460 Use the `buildfile` command line option, for example: `ant -buildfile pathetoanotherdirectory/build.xml`